# How To Run An Application On Startup Automatically?

Tags: boot, server, startup, upstart, autorun

I am using "UbuntuServer13.10" and I have Dynamic IP. So for learning purpose, I want to add a host on my dynamic IP to open my server easily from anywhere. For this purpose, I used [www.noip.com](https://www.noip.com/) script. Everything is working fine and its changing my Dynamic IP to there host automatically whenever my Dynamic IP got change. Now the problem is that for this purpose, I have to start the "No-IP" application on every boot manually that I don't want. I am using `/usr/local/bin/noip2` in terminal to start manually after starting server. So my main question is that **How to start this application on server startup/boot automatically?** Waiting for perfect and easy solution...

I have the below script provided by "No-IP" support dept. Is this ok and where To Add This...

```
####################################################### 
#! /bin/sh 
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc 
case "$1" in 
start) 
echo "Starting noip2." 
/usr/local/bin/noip2 
;; 
stop) 
echo -n "Shutting down noip2." 
killproc -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2 
;; 
*) 
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}" 
exit 1 
esac 
exit 0 
#######################################################
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add your script to the runlevel defaults:

```bsh
sudo touch /etc/init.d/noip2
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/noip2
sudo update-rc.d noip2 defaults
```

Then add this into `/etc/init.d/noip2`

```bsh
####################################################### 
#! /bin/sh 
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc 
case "$1" in 
start) 
echo "Starting noip2." 
/usr/local/bin/noip2 
;; 
stop) 
echo -n "Shutting down noip2." 
killproc -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2 
;; 
*) 
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}" 
exit 1 
esac 
exit 0 
#######################################################
```

Then restart and your script will be running.

Comment: I tried your code and it run when I login to my user and got my host updated automatically without starting manually. **But** I want to run this "No-IP" on boot/start not after login to my user account. How to make it run automatically without login any account?

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: See my updated question. Is this the script that I have to add in **rc.local** instead of the above one that you provided. If yes, then after updating the new script provided by "No-IP" support, should I add this script to the runlevel defaults as you mentioned above?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: I did all as you said but still not getting the application on startup/boot. :(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/noip2` command.

Comment: Should I do all steps again by removing previous generated and edited file or only run `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/noip2`.

Comment: Run the command and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

There is System-V link in linux which enables script  execution on different startup level.

Follow below steps:

1. make one shell script (which execute your application)
   eg.

   name **start**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /bin/bash xxx.sh
   ```
2. put this **start** to `/etc/init.d/` directory
3. now we need to put this script to start up level
4. Run command `update-rc.d start`
   now restart you PC.

hope will help you.